# SQL to find "clients" with a specific missing attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to use a `SQL` statement on 1 table in which the result is the clients who do NOT have one specific attribute?

The table exists of multiple columns. One of them is `Client`and another one is `Product`. One `client` can have several different records with different `product`-values.
Every `client` should at least have one specific `product` (for example `X`), next to a lot of different other values of `product` he can have. I would like to use a statement which returns all `clients` who don't have `product X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Using `NOT EXISTS` as following:

  ```
  SELECT client
    FROM yourTable T
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable TIN 
      WHERE TIN.product = 'product X'
        AND T.CLIENT = TIN.CLIENT
    );
  ```
- Using `NOT IN`

  ```
  SELECT client
    FROM yourTable T
   WHERE client not in 
    (SELECT tin.client FROM yourTable TIN 
      WHERE TIN.product = 'product X'
    );
  ```
- Using `group by`, as shown in the other answers

  ```
  select client
    from yourTable
  group by client
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product = 'product X' THEN 1 END) = 0;
  ```

Comment: The statements with NOT EXISTS and NOT IN work fine! I put in a "select distinct" at the top to make it a more readable list.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is one simple option:

```
SELECT client
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY client
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product = 'product X' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

This works by keeping a count, for each client, of each record which matches product X.  Assuming a client never has this product, the count would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with NOT IN.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM table1
WHERE product NOT IN ('X')
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT [Clients] FROM [tablename] WHERE Product != 'X'`

Comment: Give description about what it does and how it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery to get all records which *have* X and then in the main query get all records which are  *not* in this subset:

`SELECT DISTINCT table_name.client FROM table_name WHERE table_name.client NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_name.client FROM table_name WHERE table_name.product = 'X')`